# Convince entity context (EF1) to populate entity references

Tags: entity-framework, reference, hierarchical-data

I have an entity with self reference (generated by Entity Designer):

```
public MyEntity: EntityObject
{
    // only relevant stuff here
    public int Id { get...; set...; }
    public MyEntity Parent { get...; set...; }
    public EntityCollection<MyEntity> Children { get...; set...; }
    ...
}
```

I've written a stored procedure that returns a subtree of nodes (**not** just immediate children) from the table and returns a list of `MyEntity` objects. I'm using a stored proc to avoid lazy loading of an arbitrary deep tree. This way I get relevant subtree nodes back from the DB in a single call.

```
List<MyEntity> nodes = context.GetSubtree(rootId).ToList();
```

All fine. But when I check `nodes[0].Children`, its `Count` equals to 0. But if I debug and check `context.MyEntities.Results view`, Children enumerations get populated. Checking my result reveals children under my `node[0]`.

**How can I programaticaly force my entity context to do in-memory magic and put correct references on `Parent` and `Children` properties?**

### UPDATE 1

I've tried  calling

```
context.Refresh(ClientWins, nodes);
```

after my `GetSubtree()` call which does set relations properly, but fetches same nodes again from the DB. It's still just a workaround. But better than getting the whole set with `context.MyEntities().ToList()`.

### UPDATE 2

I've reliably solved this by using EF Extensions project. Check my answer below.

Comment: Is this EF 4 POCOs? In EF 1 you'd never do `List<MyEntity>` as a property type. Can you elaborate on how you've mapped `Children`?

Comment: It's EF1. I've updated my entity as EF generates it. I've changed `List< MyEntity >` to `EntityCollection<>`, so it's more correct. I just wanted to illustrate the relationships not the actual types. And I want EF to connect nodes when I get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The REAL solution

Based on [this article](http://code.dortikum.net/2009/11/23/mapping-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-with-entity-framework/) (read text under *The problem*), navigation properties are obviously not populated/updated when one uses stored procedures to return data.

But there's a nice manual solution to this. Use [**EF Extensions**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) project and write your own entity `Materilizer<EntityType>` where you can correctly set navigation properties like this:

```
...
ParentReference = {
    EntityKey = new EntityKey(
        "EntityContextName.ParentEntitySetname",
        new[] {
            new EntityKeyMember(
                "ParentEntityIdPropertyName",
                reader.Field<int>("FKNameFromSP")
            )
        })
}
...
```

And that's it. Calling stored procedure will return correct data, and entity object instances will be correctly related to eachother. I advise you check EF Extensions' samples, where you will find lots of nice things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign one end of the relationship. First, divide the collection:

```
var root = nodes.Where(n => n.Id == rootId).First();
var children = nodes.Where(n => n.Id != rootId);
```

Now, fix up the relationship.

In your case, you'd do either:

```
foreach (var c in children)
{
    c.Parent = root;
}
```

...or:

```
foreach (var c in children)
{
    root.Children.Add(c);
}
```

It doesn't matter which.

Note that this marks the entities as modfied. You'll need to change that if you intend to call `SaveChanges` on the context and don't want this saved.

Comment: Not exactly. My `nodes` list is a list of all descendant nodes of a particular node, not just its immediate children. So setting all to have the same parent (root in your case) is not correct.

Comment: OK, that wasn't at all clear from your question. My suspicion, then, is that your proc is returning incorrect or incomplete data.